# Artificial Neural Network to Predict Output from 1 to 5

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am trying to build an ANN that takes in "y" values labels which are numbers from 1 to 5 associated with 9 features each. I made a network in keras with only rectifier "relu" activation functions from the input layer to the output layer included, but I am getting low training accuracies of 0.1915 at all epochs from 1 to 100, signifying there is a problem in the fundamental architecture of the network. How should I fix this for my case of predicting a single output which is in range [0,5]? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#layers
#layers
#layers
#...

model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (4*x)+1))
```

> Warning: if this is a classification problem, you should be using "one-hot encoded" outputs.